# Connect to Salesforce REST API using SSO and Python

Tags: python, salesforce

I know it's possible to interact with the Salesforce API using a username and password using the library [simple-salesforce](https://pypi.org/project/simple-salesforce/) but I am wondering if you can use SSO instead. In short, I think it's possible because I can use the tool [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) and be authorized via SSO to use the API. However, I don't know how APIs work and can't find resources on how to use SSO as a method to connect to the Salesforce API using Python. Has anyone else figured this out?